# How to get a full description of an activity in cleartool?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I used ClearQuest to export a query to a csv containing information about all my developer activities. However, the description is truncated. Is there a cleartool command that can output the full description of a given activity?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
cleartool descr -l activity:MyActivity@\myPVob
```

You need to use the fully qualified name of the activity: `activity:xxx@\mypvob` (Windows) or `activity:xxx@/vobs/mypvob` (Unix)

You can also look into [`fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm), in order to describe only what you want out of the long description given by a simple `descr -l`.

- `%[versions]CQp` would list all the versions of a given activity
- `%c` would only display the comment associated with the activity

So this could be enough:

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%c" activity:MyActivity@\myPVob
or
cleartool lsactivity -fmt "%c" activity:MyActivity@\myPVob
```

The headline would be obtained with `%[headline]p`.

This data should be available, even though in a ClearQuest-enabled project, any UCM activity is auto-transitioned to a ClearQuest work item, [linked through its SQUID](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/rtnv1r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.rcc/rcc/7.0/Operations/ucm_cq_/player.html) (SUM ClearQuest Integration Doodad).
As [mentioned here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=36944), `%[crm_record_id]p` and `%[crm_state]p` give you access to the ClearQuest® record ID and the activity's state.

---

However, regarding the comment specifically, you won't find it on the ClearCase activity.
As illustrated by [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21239440), it looks like this:

```
cleartool lsact -long ACT00032163
activity "ACT00032163"
16-May-06.14:58:24 by Joe User (jou)
 "Created automatically as a result of 'Work On' action in ClearQuest"
 owner: jou
 group: liteline
 stream: jou-act3g-v1.0-2@/vobs/projects
 title: Draft of Test cases for UC01-1,2,3,7,8,10,11,30,32 and 04-2
 change set versions:
   ...
```

So the ClearCase comment is a generated one.

For accessing the Description field of a ClearQuest record, you need to use the ClearQuest API (VB script for instance):

- first to [build a ClearQuest session](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v8r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.api.tut.doc/topics/cqapi_overview_crs.htm),
- then [getting the right record by its id](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v8r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.apiref.doc/topics/c_get_entity_objs.htm), which you have through `%[crm_record_id]p`, as mentioned above.

That would be something like:

```
require CQPerlExt; 
$CQsession = CQSession::Build();

set cqrecord = sessionObj.GetEntity("defect", "BUGID00000031")
set cqdescrfield = cqrecord.GetFieldValue("Description")
set cqdescr = cqdescrfield .GetValue()
```

Comment: What I need to get is the description that the developer entered when he created the activity (the description field).

Comment: @Amir That should be the comment (%c)

Comment: using `%c` didn't return what I expected (I don't have it next to me right now, but it was something like "created automatically through a 'Work On' action").

Comment: can you regard my previous comment please?

Comment: @AmirRachum: yes, sorry for the delay. I have updated the answer to address your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like...

```
foreach act ( `cleartool lsact -s` )    
    set changeset = `cleartool lsact -fmt "%[versions]p" $act`
    echo $changeset | tr ' ' '\n' >> $tmpoutput
end

foreach line ( "`cat $tmpoutput`" ) 
    set file=`echo $line | sed -e "s|\(.*\)@@.*|\1|"`
end
```

This list the changed set for the activity (excluding @@).

Source:

http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/961/list-files-changed-in-clearcase-ucm-stre?fromPage=1